# Adding external xml view to current view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I've created a form as following (**form.xml**):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/formLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android :text="Name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- Many more things-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

If above form was created through code (say FormView), then in each activity I could have used something like

```
<com.example.FormView
    android:id="@+id/fv1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But since form is created using xml as shown above, how do I use it in numerous activities?
I want to use above form layout(form.xml) as user control in all the activities.

---

I tried following, but it throws `NullPointerException` at last line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
View form= (View) findViewById(R.id.formLayout);
mainLayout.addView(form);
```

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: have you created FormView class in your project??

Comment: NO. I just gave an example that if form was created using a class i.e. FormView, then it can be used everywhere. But how do I use xml file in various views?

Comment: The null pointer exception is because of the fact that you are setting the content view to Main.xml but are trying to resolve R.id.formlayout which is not a part of main hence your form object would always be null. you can try using the layout inflator to use ur xml

Comment: can u show example code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at here [Re-using layouts](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

It shows how you can re-use your existing layout to include it in other.

Answer (score -1):

what exactly you are trying to do, then i will write code for you, use below code and put your widgets in that and done...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.XMLFileName);
```

Comment: this will set content from ONLY `XMLFileName`. What if I want to add another layout into current layout?